# Can a router send ARP requests to hosts?

Tags: router, arp, layer2, layer3, pcap

I play with `libpcap` in C recently to create an arp sniffer program that captures arp requests on the air. I came up with a strange effect. **I captured arp requests from my router.** I don't know if this is a bug of my program, but I was curious (even more after I analyzed the packet and found that the operation code was set to `1` which means we have to do with arp request). Is this ever possible? I didn't found any entry for a similar question on the Internet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ARP is used by a host on a LAN to resolve a layer-3 address to a layer-2 address so that a frame can be built for the LAN. A router is just another host on a LAN, and it will need to resolve layer-3 addresses to layer-2 addresses, the same way a PC on a LAN does.

Comment: I woudn't call a router a host (but I totally agree otherwise).

Comment: In layer-2 (LAN) protocols, there are no routers, only hosts.